# Laravel 4 Eloquent Problems Select with hasMany Relation

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have 2 models : Album & Photo.

Album hasMany Photo and photo belongsTo('album','id');

Just Like:

```
class Photo extends Eloquent {


protected $table = 'photo';

public function album(){
    return $this->belongsTo('album','id');
}}
```

and

```
class Album extends Eloquent {


protected $table = 'album';

public function photo()
{
    return $this->hasMany('photo');
}}
```

i have no problem until i want to try select Album Name and show first photo on an Album.

I am trying this code:

```
<?php $albums= Album::get();?>
@foreach($albums as $album)
    <pre>{{$photo = $album->photo->first()}}</pre>
@endforeach
```

and output :

```
{"id":1,"images":"1.png","album_id":1,"created_at":"2014-09-08 03:54:36","updated_at":"2014-09-08 03:54:36"}

{"id":3,"images":"3.jpg","album_id":3,"created_at":"2014-09-08 04:30:35","updated_at":"2014-09-08 04:30:35"}
```

it's mean i have 2 album and i already select first photo of each album.

and when i trying to call images attributes it's error:

```
echo "$album->photo->first()->images";
```

error : 
[image]

Comment: Whats the error message you get?

Comment: @lukasgeiter i already edit error message picture

Comment: Thanks, but sadly the interesting part is not visible. Could you click on the first entry on the left ("handleViewException") and make sure the frame on the right is scrolled to the top so we can see the actual error message? Thanks

Comment: @lukasgeiter sorry i didn't realize that right part is scrolled down. now i reupload

Comment: Hmm that looks weird. What if you try to access another property instead? like: `$album->photo->first()->id`

Comment: Can you please show us your database structure? And try to use `{{ var_dump($photo = $album->photo->first()) }}` for the output

Comment: @lukasgeiter problem solved thanks for everything i didn't realize my third album and there's no photo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely that you have an Album in your database which does not have a Photo associated with it. So when you loop over your albums and echo `{{ $album->photo->first() }}`, it simply outputs `null` for any album that does not have a photo (because there is, obviously, no `first()`) without throwing an error. However, when you try to access the `image` property of the album that doesn't have a photo, you are *trying to get a property of a non-object*, i.e. you are asking for the `image` property of `null`. Hence an error is thrown.

You can resolve this by wrapping your output in an `@if` statement that checks to make sure a photo exists, before trying to access its `image` property:

```
@foreach($albums as $album)
    @if (count($album->photo))
        {{ $album->photo->first()->image }}
    @endif
@endforeach
```

There is a shortcut for this, using blade's `or` syntax, which checks for existence before trying to echo the result. This allows you to remove the `@if` statement:

```
@foreach($albums as $album)
    {{ $album->photo->first()->id or null }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: A couple other suggestions, unrelated to your error, but good practice: it is a convention to name your one-to-many relations plural nouns, i.e. `photos`, to help make your code more readable. And your model logic (`$albums= Album::all();`) doesn't belong in your view, but rather in a controller.

Comment: Since his code `<pre>{{$photo = $album->photo->first()}}</pre>` works, I don't think it's a problem of not having a Photo associated. But Anyway, a count would definitely be necesary

Comment: No, `{{$photo = $album->photo->first()}}` works fine because it will return `null` for albums without photos. So when it's echoed in the `@foreach` loop, albums that *do* have photos will display a result, while albums without photos will display nothing. The loop runs fine because `->first()` just returns `null`, which is not an error. It's only when you try to access a property on `null` that it becomes an error. (I suspect, from the output, that the album with `id` of `2` is the one without a photo.)

Comment: Ahhh yes you are right. That should be the problem.

Comment: This issue pops up often in Laravel, when looping over related records in a view. Turns out there is a shorthand version that can do away with the `@if (count...)`, with an `or` shortcut. So it's possible to just use one line, `{{ $album->photo->first()->id or null }}`

Comment: @damiani wow that's work. i didn't realize my third album have no photo then it make it error

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would recommend when using Eloquent to retrieve all entries in a table, use ::all() instead of ::get(), as shown in [Basic Usage](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#basic-usage). Not sure if it's causing the problem, but you may want to follow the docs.

Secondly, in relationship, the first parameter to hasMany and belongsTo should be the model class name. So it should be 'Album' and 'Photo', first letter capitalized.

Judging from you output, album_id seems to be the foreign key name. So in your Photo class, change the relationship into the following:

```
public function album(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Album','album_id');
}
```

Just ran your code, the issue is that you did not define the primary key for you models. Laravel will assume you are using 'id' as the primary key, and if that's not the case, your relationship will break. And it's always better to explicitly define what the primary key is, so as to avoid confusion when foreign keys are involved. So please add to the model class:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'album_id';
```

You can revise your code and see if the error persists. It's not showing up in my end now.

Comment: no problem with my code before and i already follow your suggestion but still error. i already upload error message picture